# OpenStreetMap: Export A Cycle Path

Tags: geospatial, openstreetmap, latitude-longitude

I would like to download this [cycle route](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/1077494#map=12/51.4644/-0.1357)
to then put into my mapping software. I use Insite.

To import into Insite I will need to have the long/lats on the cycle route to then create a continuous line.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

See [API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API) for the documentation of the OSM editing API.

If you already know the relation ID (here: 1077494) you can download it including all members using the following URL:

```
https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/1077494/full
```

Note the `/full` at the end of the URL.

Now comes the hard part: constructing the path from all [nodes](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node) and [ways](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way) that are referenced by the [relation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation). See [OSM XML](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML) for a documentation of the OSM XML format. Also keep in mind that relations don't necessarily need to be sorted, their members can be referenced in arbitrary order.

The easiest way is going to https://cycling.waymarkedtrails.org to download the specific cycle (or hiking, horse, ski, ...) route from OSM in GPX format.